# How to space out image buttons in TableRow?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm trying to space out my image buttons in my table row (so it doesn't touch each other. It doesn't seem to space out. Can anyone tell me how to? Thanks for any responses.

Heres a screenshot:
[image: http://i.imgur.com/xqPIfXJ.png]

My activity_main xml file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#ff000000"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical">


<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/adViewFunny">

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">

            <ImageButton
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/iLikeTurtlesButton"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:src="@drawable/bluesound"
                    android:background="@drawable/transparent"
                    android:onClick="PlayILikeTurtles"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:layout_column="0" />

            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/imageButton12"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:src="@drawable/bluesound"
                android:background="@drawable/transparent"
                android:onClick="PlayILikeTurtles"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_column="14" />
        </TableRow>


    </TableLayout>



</ScrollView>


<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/adViewFunny"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    ads:adUnitId="XXXX"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"/>
```

Comment: please elaborate what you mean by "space out" if possible post some excerpts from your xml layout. Do you want to stretch the buttons or do you want space between the buttons?

Comment: Added my xml file and added a screenshot - thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To center the children of the TableRow, add `android:gravity="center"` to the TableRow.

To add some space between the children you can use a divider like this:

Create a drawable `drawable/horizontal_spacer.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <!-- define how much spacing you want -->
    <size android:width="10dp"/>
    <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent"/>
</shape>
```

Then use `android:divider` and `android:showDividers` on your TableRow:

```
<TableRow
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:divider="@drawable/horizontal_spacer"
    android:showDividers="middle">

    <ImageButton
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:id="@+id/iLikeTurtlesButton"
       ... />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageButton12"
        ... />
</TableRow>
```